# Using C# and gppg, how would I construct an abstract syntax tree?

Tags: c#, syntax, tree, abstract, gppg

Is there a way to do this almost out-of-the-box?

I could go and write a big method that would use the collected tokens to figure out which leaves should be put in which branches and in the end populate a TreeNode object, but since gppg already handled everything by using supplied regular expressions, I was wondering if there's an easier way? Even if not, any pointers as to how best to approach the problem of creating an AST would be appreciated.

Apologies if I said anything silly, I'm only just beginning to play the compiler game. :)

Answer (score 1):

See MGrammar and Oslo...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/oslo

http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL31/

Answer (score 1):

1. In your syntax file declare a property which will keep the root of your AST:

   ```
   {%
   public BatchNode Batch;
   public ErrorHandler yyhldr;
   private TransformationContext _txContext = TransformationContext.Instance;
   %}
   ```
2. Start writing your grammar with actions which build nodes of your AST:

   ```
   Batch
       : StatementList {Batch = new BatchNode($1.Statements);}
       ;

   StatementList
       : Statement {$$.Statements = new List<StatementNode>(); $$.Statements.Add($1.Statement); }
       | StatementList Statement   {$$.Statements = $1.Statements; $$.Statements.Add($2.Statement);}
       ;
   ```
3. Call parser:

   ```
   var parser = new Parser.Parser();
   var scanner = new Scanner();
   parser.scanner = scanner;
   scanner.SetSource(sourceString, 0);
   bool result = parser.Parse();
   if (result)
       HandleMyAst(parser.Batch)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/), I did a simple .NET compiler written in C# with it few years back.